# Eclipse Kepler Navigator Issue with Focus on Active Task

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, mylyn

OS: **Gentoo Linux**

Java VM: **Oracle JRE 1.7.0.25 [oracle-jre-bin-1.7]**

I installed **Eclipse Kepler** *x86* at home and *x64* at work from the official website. Also I've installed **PDT** and **Mylyn**. Here's what I noticed:

In *x64* edition "**Focus on Active Task**" button is missing, but it's available in *x86* edition:
[image: Focus on Active Task button missing]

I've even tried to copy **.metadata** catalogue from home workspace to work. As a result all settings have been added correctly, but this button is still missing...

Also the **.metadata** catalogue probably has some leftovers from **Eclipse Indigo** that I used before.

How can I add this button to *x64* edition?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

You can download Kepler with preinstalled mylyn. Like "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" package.